# Build Scripts stays on None even after adding scripts in Project's root

Tags: android, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-test

I am checking the AppCenter system for our Android and iOS apps.
I need to run a pre build script and after adding it to the relevant Git branch I am still seeing None under Build Scripts in the menu.
The script is very basic one at the moment, just creating a password file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo 'mypass' > ~/.myapp/keys/password
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what directory are you putting the script file in?